# Why does the Pied Piper neighborhood smell like bacon?

Tags: silicon-valley

At the end of Silicon Valley's S05E02, Richard, Dinesh and Gilfoyle are kicked out of their homes by Jian-Yang. As the episode ends, Gilfoyle asks

> Why does the whole neighborhood smell like bacon?

I don't get the joke, is it some reference to a prior part of the episode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Earlier in the episode, Jian-Yang "cremated" a huge pig. The smoke from that would have permeated the whole neighborhood. For the episode, it was funnier to say that the neighborhood smelled like bacon, though in reality it would have smelled more like burned pork (but probably even less pleasant).

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now!